How to draw the boundary line of intersecting region of a ContourPlot3D and a Graphics3D?
I have mathematical expressions of a cylinder (oriented along the x-axis) and a parabola. And I can easily plot both the surfaces using ContourPlot3D as shown below.
plot = ContourPlot3D[y^2/2 +(z - 28)^2/2 == 70, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -10,   80}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.3]]]


and
plot2 = ContourPlot3D[-(x^2/2) + 10*z == -20, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -10, 80}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3]]]



I can also draw the cylinder when its axis is rotated through an angle with the help of RotationTransform and Graphics3D (see below).
plot3 = Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[First@plot,RotationTransform[\[Pi]/4, {0, 0, 1}]]}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]


I am pretty much interested in intersecting regions. So, When both the surfaces are plotted using ContourPlot3D, I managed to draw their intersecting orbits using the following code, where the intersecting orbits are represented in blue color.
ContourPlot3D[{y^2/2 + (z - 28)^2/2 ==70, -(x^2/2) + 10*z == -20}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -10,80}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.3],Specularity[White, 30]],Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]]}, BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, _} -> Directive[Thick, Blue]},[![enter image description here][1]][1]PlotTheme ->"Scientific", PlotPoints -> 10]


But the above code is not valid when one surface is in ContourPlot3D (i.e. parabla shown in plot2) and another surface is in Graphics3D (i.e. that one where axis of cylinder is rotated shown in plot3).
Using the code (which is given below) I am getting the intersection of Plot2 and plot3, but I am not able to get the intersectng orbits. Because, in Graphics3D, BoundaryStyle/MeshStyle/RegionIntersection/DiscretizeRegion etc. are not valid.
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], First@plot2,GeometricTransformation[First@plot,RotationTransform[\[Pi]/4, {0, 0, 1}]],BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]}, Axes -> True,AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]


I can see the intersecting region, but I would like to surround that area with a more prominent line of a different color just like the previous intersecting orbits. Here, I cannot figure out how to apply the boundary line.


For the cylinder equation f[x_, y_, z_] := y^2/2 + (z - 28)^2/2 - 70==0, we rotate the coordinate by (RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 0, 1}]@{x, y, z} and get the implicit form of the new cylinderh[x_, y_, z_, θ_] :=  f @@ (RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 0, 1}]@{x, y, z})==0. After that we use it as the MeshFunction to draw the intersection of  parabola.

Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_, z_] := y^2/2 + (z - 28)^2/2 - 70;
g[x_, y_, z_] := -(x^2/2) + 10*z + 20;
h[x_, y_, z_, θ_] := 
  f @@ (RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 0, 1}]@{x, y, z});
θ = π/4;
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[
  g[x, y, z] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -10, 
   80}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, h[x, y, z, θ]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3]], 
  PlotRange -> Full, MeshStyle -> Thick, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
 ContourPlot3D[
  h[x, y, z, θ] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 
   50}, {z, -10, 80}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> None, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50], PlotRange -> All]



Instead of applying GeometricTransform to Graphics3D objects, I suggest
that you should apply the linear transformation to the original equation. Note that the transformation for equation (function) is inverse to the one for points, so the sign of rotation angle is reversed:
rotation=Thread[{x,y,z}->RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/4,{0,0,1}][{x,y,z}]]
(* {x->x/Sqrt[2]+y/Sqrt[2],y->-(x/Sqrt[2])+y/Sqrt[2],z->z} *)

newcylinder=Simplify[y^2/2+(z-28)^2/2==70/.rotation]
 (* x^2+y^2+2 (644-56 z+z^2)==2 x y *)

ContourPlot3D[
{newcylinder,-(x^2/2)+10*z==-20},
{x,-50,50},{y,-50,50},{z,-10,80},
Mesh->None,PlotRange->Full,Boxed->True,Axes->True,
ContourStyle->{Directive[Yellow,Opacity[0.3],Specularity[White,30]],
Directive[Green,Opacity[0.3],Specularity[White,30]]},
BoundaryStyle->{1->None,2->None,{1,2}->Directive[Thick,Blue]},
PlotTheme->"Scientific",PlotPoints->20,Axes->True,AxesLabel->{x,y,z}]



After posting my answer, I found cvgmt's answer. My answer is in the same line as his.
